# Elasticsearch using lightweight query string search for array elements

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to use the lightweight query string to do a search on documents that have an array field:

```
{
    "list":["A", "b"]
}
```

I don't want to use Request body search queries like all the examples of the web are using, I'd rather use something like:

```
"http://localhost:9200/patientsummary/patient/_search?q=list:A"
```

Because I need to use the restful API. The above returns zero results. Is this possible?

Comment: What you posted works for me, at least with a default mapping. Can you post your mapping? Maybe the problem is in it somewhere.

Comment: Hi, it seems to be working for me now... I'm not sure what I was doing wrong before but I was getting some weird errors about shards. Its working fine now.